# Getting keyboard event without waiting for enter pressed in command line app

Tags: c++, linux, command-line

I need to use a keyboard emulator, where users will do something, and the application will receive a button press. normally I'd get use input in console applications through the std::getline method, but that needs a carriage return to work. is there a portable, or if not portable, linux specific way to intercept a button press without enter to be pressed in a command line, c++11 application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) or maybe [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)